# JUnit test, Hibernate and Unknown entity error

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I'm trying to persist a very simple class using Hibernate. I'm **not** using Spring, I'm **not** using mapping files, just **plain annotations**. I **am** using `javax.persistence.Entity` instead of `org.hibernate.Entity`. Still, when running a JUnit test (located in a different package than the class, a test one), I'm getting `testAddUser caused an ERROR: Unknown entity: restauracja.PersonalInfo`.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** This is how I initialize my session factory:

```
private final static SessionFactory factory;
static {
    Configuration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

And run the test:

```
@Test
public void testAddUser() {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    PersonalInfo pi = new PersonalInfo("Jan", "Kowalski", "Krótka 6a", "Gniezno", 123456l);

    session.saveOrUpdate(pi);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

}
```

Comment: show how you config it and use it in test launcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate usually has a collection of classes that it knows about and has investigated for annotations.  I suspect that you need to add your `restauracja.PersonalInfo` class to that collection.  For example, in our test harness we do something like:

```
AnnotationConfiguration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
for (Class<?> clazz : databaseConfig.getHibernateClasses()) {
    cfg.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);
}
```

Each of the classes that is used by the specific unit test needs to specify all of the classes that `hibernate` needs for the test must be in that list.  I suspect that the list of classes is probably in the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file and you just need to add the missing class(es) to that list.

Comment: Side note: AnnotationConfiguration has been deprecated in favor of Configuration.

Comment: Um, nope, my `hibernate.cfg.xml` only contains dialect (MySQL) configuration (user, pass, database). I've used NetBeans' automatic class generation from DB schema tool.

Comment: @IneQuation Have you tried adding `cfg.addAnnotatedClass(restauracja.PersonalInfo.class);` before the session factory is created?

Comment: Yeah, I just did that and it worked - I'm running up against other exceptions now which are apparently a result of my poor database setup. ;)

So, do the classes always need to be explicitly listed somewhere?

Comment: @IneQuation Yes.  Hibernate needs to know which classes are going to be persisted so it can mark them up.  I don't know if there is some setting to have hibernate discover them automagically.